# Creating 3D model for SLARToolkit

Tags: silverlight, 3d, augmented-reality

I am working on an AR based web app where I need to display some product images on a marker. I found SLARToolkit and the samples are working fine. But now I need to display the 3D models of the products instead of sample "3D world and cubes". As I am a developer, I don't have any idea about 3D modeling though I have a designer in my team. Now I need to know, how to convert the images to 3D models that will be placed on the markers? Are there any softwares which can do the conversions?

Comment: images as such cannot be converted to 3d . although you can use some technique to conver the image object like using shadows and all

Answer (score 0):

This si a link that lets you play with 3d effect

[3d](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470131%28VS.96%29.aspx)

and I can suggest you to drop a shadow in silverlight using

```
<DropShadowEffect Direction="0" BlurRadius="10" 
              ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.6" Color="White" />
```